# Problema con UTF8 e ISO-8859

Tags: php, utf-8

Tengo un archivo que hace llamadas a varios archivos en formato utf8 y otros a ISO-8859.
Necesito que la salida sea en utf8, el problema está en que si a todo el archivo realizo un utf8_encode, los ISO-8859 se ven bien pero los utf8 se ven mal porque estoy volviendo a encodearlos a utf8. Estos archivos ISO-8859 no puedo cambiarlos porque no tengo autorización para ello, por lo que debo encontrar una solución para que teniendo un archivo con llamadas a archivos en utf-8 e ISO-8850 pueda obtener una salida unica utf8 correcta.
Alguna idea?

Comment: *"un archivo con llamadas a archivos"* ¿todos los archivos son phps?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es detectar el tipo de codificación y actuar en consecuencia: si no es UTF-8 traducir a UTF8 en caso contrario dejar tal cual.
Esto lo puedes lograr con mb_detect_encoding($contenido_fichero). Esto te devuelve la codificación de la cadena, que será el contenido del archivo. Puedes leerlo con file_get_contents($parh_archivo), es la manera más simple.

Comment: Entonces tendría que ir a cada include y verificar su encoding? 
No hay una manera que se haga global? lo digo porque son demasiados includes en plantilla

Comment: Te toca modificar el código. ¿Todos los archivos se leen de la misma forma? Pon el código dónde se vea como se llama a esos archivos externos.

Comment: He visto que si hago un 
$html = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-15//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $html);
y luego un utf8_encode($html);

Veo que lo unico que falla es el emoji que no se ve, todo lo demás aparece bien. Tienes idea de como saber cual ISO es compatible con los emojis?

Comment: Por lo que se con UNICODE UTF-16, el caso es que cada emoji son como 4 bytes  para ser codificados en UTF-8 el como ya se me escapa.

Comment: @Minniek estas convirtiendo todo a ISO-8859-15 que no soporta emojis y esos caracteres y cualquier otro que no cubra ISO-8859-15 se perderán. La recomendación es utilizar UNICODE, con UTF-*